# Showing only one scrollbar per axis for scroll-synced elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a web page that allows a user to compare two tables of data side-by-side. The tables are scroll-synced to each other, so that scrolling one also scrolls the other. While the number of columns and rows are dynamic, both tables will always have equal amounts.

The only "issue" I've been having with this is that a scrollbar shows up in each table for both the horizontal and vertical axes. Since a table can't be scrolled independently, it makes more sense for there to only be one scroll for each axis. The vertical scrollbar should show on the right hand side of the parent element, and the horizontal scrollbar should show at the bottom of the parent element, continuing along the entire length (under both tables).

The only way I've been able to think of that could potentially achieve this effect would be to do something like set both tables to absolute/fixed positioning, measure the amount of overflow in the table, and reproduce that amount of overflow in the parent using hidden elements, then syncing the scroll of the parent to both the tables. However, this seems like a pretty overkill/silly method to solve this problem.

For reference, I've put together a Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4pyx0Lzk/2/)

And here is an image of the [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yJs4.png)

```js
function init() {
  let isScrollSyncing = false;
  let table1 = document.querySelector('#table1');
  let table2 = document.querySelector('#table2');

  let scrollListener = (target, src) => {
    if (!isScrollSyncing) {
      isScrollSyncing = true;
      target.scrollTop = src.scrollTop;
      target.scrollLeft = src.scrollLeft;
    } else {
      isScrollSyncing = false;
    }
  };

  table1.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    scrollListener(table2, table1);
  });
  table2.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    scrollListener(table1, table2);
  });
}

init();
```

```css
#compareTables {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
}

#table1 .cell {
  background: grey;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='compareTables'>
  <div id='table1' class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div id='table2' class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would it be alright if the scrollbar only appears on one of the tables but scrolls two tables at once?

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I gave that a try previously, but had issues with aligning the rows between the tables - one table has the content offset to make room for the bottom scrollbar, but the other table content isn't offset, so the rows don't line up anymore. Using overflow: overlay meant that the final row of data in the table got partially obscured.

Comment: I see. I think that your best bet would be to use a custom scrollbar instead of the browser-provided one. Would that be okay?

Comment: As long as the user is still able to scroll vertically using the scrollwheel, horizontally using the scrollwheel + shift, and by clicking+dragging on the scrollbar, that's fine!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly is this what you mean?

> View it in `full screen` for clarity.

```js
function init() {
  let isScrollSyncing = false;
  let table1 = document.querySelector('#table1');
  let table2 = document.querySelector('#table2');

  let scrollListener = (target, src) => {
    if (!isScrollSyncing) {
      isScrollSyncing = true;
      target.scrollTop = src.scrollTop;
      target.scrollLeft = src.scrollLeft;
    } else {
      isScrollSyncing = false;
    }
  };

  table1.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    scrollListener(table2, table1);
  });
  table2.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    scrollListener(table1, table2);
  });
}

init();
```

```css
#compareTables {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#table1 {
  width: auto;
}

#table2 {
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
}

#table1 .cell {
  background: grey;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='compareTables'>
  <div id='table1' class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div id='table2' class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Not quite - both tables should still be scrollable horizontally (ie, the table itself should be scrolled, not the parent).
The purpose is to compare data from one table to another, so if I'm looking at Columns 10-14 in Table 1, I need to be able to see Columns 10-14 in Table 2 as well.

Comment: Ok, so there should be 2(tbl1 and tbl2) scrolls for horizontal and one right scroll for both?

Comment: Ideally there should be only 1 scrollbar for each axis.
The horizontal scrollbar on the bottom should control the horizontal scroll of each individual table, but the scrollbar should continue the length of both tables.

Comment: Yeah just modified the code, having single scroll for both tables.

Comment: Thanks for giving it another go! Unfortunately, this is still not exactly what I'm aiming for. In the example you've provided, the user would be unable to see the same columns and rows from each table at the same time.
Sorry for not explaining it well - I've added an image of the desired result to the original post so hopefully that will help.